# Theme function in Drupal 6

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

Im using Drupal 6.x. In my page i have the following code which prints a paged table.

```
$headers = array(array('data' => t('Node ID'),'field' => 'nid','sort'=>'asc' ),
        array('data' => t('Title'),'field' => 'title'),
      );


print theme('pager_table','SELECT nid,title FROM {node_revisions}', 5, $headers );
```

Is there a way i can pass the rows of a table as an array to the theme function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know `theme_pager_table`, it's not a part of Drupal core. What you can do, it to wrap your sql in [`pager_query()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/pager_query/6), then you can loop through your results and create the table rows like normal. `pager_query()` will handle adding the `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in the query.

Doing this you cam use the normal [`theme_table`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/thene_table/6) and just add the pager with [`theme_pager`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_pager/6). (Remember to use the [`theme`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme/6), wrapper function instead of calling the theme functions directly)